# How to provide credentials as user input runtime during python automation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-input

How to automate the Facebook login without hard-coding my username and password?

Comment: It won't be an *automated* process without hard-coding the details. You could use `input("Enter username")` before calling `send_keys` and the same for password. But not sure how that will *automate* the process.

Comment: Ah it is fine, if that username and password needs to be get as a input at  run-time.

Comment: Is it good to hard-code our credential while automating? or it will be secure when we provide info at run-time?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the **Facebook Login** without hard-coding the *username* and *password* you can use the `input()` function to take the *user input* from the console as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
emailid = input("What is your emailid?(Press enter at the end to continue):")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']").send_keys(emailid)
password = input("What is your password?(Press enter at the end to continue):")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'u_0_')][@value='Log In']").click()
```

Console Output :

```
What is your emailid?(Press enter at the end to continue):gomathisubramanian@gmail.com
What is your password?(Press enter at the end to continue):gomathisubramanian
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use Facebook OAuth API, never hard-code password, some references:

[Facebook SDK for Python](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

[Python Social Auth documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/facebook.html)

[Facebook OAuth 2 Tutorial](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/facebook.html)

Comment: Upvoting for the the effective references.